# Insert order into magento manually

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I've created my own checkout with `codeigniter`, using `magento` functions. Now, I want to insert the products I've added into checkout cart to `magento` sales but I don't find how to do it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

You can used magento soap api or trigger your code on a observer

Comment: I'm trying to buy something without using onepage checkout with ajax or with magento functions but i don't know how to do it. Can you help me? I just want to buy the current order saved in checkout card.